# jquery Animate only once

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons that, on click, display one of two content divs. Code for that:

```
$("input[name='registrationType']").click(function () {
    var registrationType = $(this).attr('id');
    if (!registrationType) {
        return;
    }
    $("#contributorForm, #studentForm").hide();
    if (registrationType == "Student") {
        $("#studentForm").show();
    } else if (registrationType == "Contributor") {
        $("#contributorForm").show();
    }
});
```

I wanted to add a simple animation, `.show('slow')` to this process. As I thought about it though, I realized I only wanted it to use the animation the first time one of the radio buttons is clicked. Is there a way to do this without having to put in some logic to determine if it's the first click (e.g. before my hide logic, check to see if they're both hidden, which is the "on load" state), then coding something like this:

```
if (registrationType == "Student") {
    if(firstClick) {
        $("#studentForm").show('slow');
    } else {
        $("#studentForm").show();
    }
}
```

Just seems like a lot of extra code for something that is relatively simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Solution

```
$("input[name='registrationType']").click(function() {
   var regType = $(this).attr('id');
   if (!regType) return;

   $('div[id$="Form"]').hide();
   var contro = $('div[id^="' + regType.toLowerCase() + '"]');
   if ($(contro).attr("data") != null) $(contro).show();
   else $(contro).show('slow');
   $('div[id$="Form"]').attr("data", "shown");
});​
```

The [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aJSxN/4/) on jsFiddle.net.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: how does that solve my problem of animating with .show('slow') only the first time without having to write a whole bunch of boilerplate, while still animating on the other click events? Remember, this is a radio button setup where users can toggle back and forth.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aJSxN/2/). Does it work for you? Accordingly will update answer.

Comment: No. perhaps I'm not articulating what I was looking for. I'm quite familiar with how to animate on radio button click. What I was looking for was a less verbose way to do so. [Here is the current code I'm using](http://jsfiddle.net/aJSxN/3/) - The first click of a radio button animates the panel, regardless of which one is clicked. subsequent clicks display the proper panel, but don't animate.